# Run a stored procedure in a multithreaded process

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, jta

I have this method which iterate over a list and calls a stored procedure. It worked fine.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class SomeService{

@Autowired    
MyJpaConfiguration myJpaConfiguration ;

private String runProcedure(...){           
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        EntityManager entityManager = myJpaConfiguration.mainUnitEM();
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL PROCEDURE(params...)");    
        query.setParameter(...);                
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
}
```

Now, to speed up the process, I want to do the same thing but in parallel calls, so my code becomes

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class SomeService{

@Autowired
MyJpaConfiguration myJpaConfiguration ;

private String runProcedure(...){       
    ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());  
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
     executor.submit(new Callable<String>(){
                        public String call() throws Exception {
                            EntityManager entityManager = myJpaConfiguration.mainUnitEM();
                            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL PROCEDURE(params...)");    
                            query.setParameter(...);                
                            query.executeUpdate();
                            return "Ok";
                          }
                    });     
    }
}
}
```

My problem is when running the piece of code in parallel, I get this error :

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

I understand that for some reason the new thread doesn't find the current transaction context so I tried to start a transaction manually by doing

```
 entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
...
 entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

but I get

```
A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
```

which makes sens because it's a container managed transaction.

At this point, I just don't know how the transactions should managed in a multithreaded environment.

I use Spring3.2, Hibernate 3.6, atomikos 3.8 for JTA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TransactionTemplate (see [the example](http://liguoliang.com/2012/transaction-management-using-spring-and-hibernate/))

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate txTemplate;
/**
 * Insert new user using transactionTemplate.
 * @param user
 */
public void insertUserByTxTemplate(final User user) {
    txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {

        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus txStatus) {
            try {
                Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                session.save(user);
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception throwed!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                txStatus.setRollbackOnly();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

In you can just wrap the stored procedure call in the TransactionCallback.

Comment: This answer will solve your problem, but it doesn't explain why.  Note that JPA sessions are _NOT_  thread safe, and Spring managed transactions are thread explody.